# Java: removing part of the string starting from "(" and ending with ")"

Tags: java, regex, string

Given the string `"Hello World (27348)"`.

How would you convert this too `"Hello World"` by specifically removing part of the string starting from `"("` and ending with `")"` with regex?

```
string.replaceAll("???", "");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why it needs to be done with regex:

```
string.substring(0, string.indexOf("("));
```

If you *must* use regex:

```
string.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "")
```

The latter is different in that it removes everything between (and including) the paren whereas the former removes everything after `(` even if there are characters after `)`.

Comment: regex probably needed for input like `"Hello (27348) World"`

Comment: @jlordo yes, exactly, hence why I provided both solutions

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
"Hello World (27348)".replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "")
```

you have to escape the brackets because they are meta characters in regex world. to treat them as normal character you should escape `em with back slashes.